# Set an android app/notification to run at boot

Tags: android, boot

I have searched but can't find anything. Is there an offcial way to start app or just the notification of the app at boot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have the a service for your app that accepts the `BOOT_COMPLETE` intent.

Here is a great example of this being done:

http://androidgps.blogspot.com/2008/09/starting-android-service-at-boot-time.html